# SetWinEventHook to catch a global destroyed process

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I'm working on a project in C++ that have to show me, real time, what application has been closed.
I have alrdy seen different approach and i have already discard some of this like polling with EnumWindows and Event Trancing Window (SetWindowsHook) because it need an injection in dll.

Now i'm working with the function SetWinEventHook that i call like this:

```
hWinEventHook1 = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY,
        NULL, HandleWinEvent, 0, 0,
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
```

When the CALLBACK is called the HWND that i get is the HWND of the explorer.exe instead of the HWND of the process that was closed.

How can i retrive the HWND of the process that i need?

Comment: at first you get is the HWND of windows which actually closed. you mistake about `explorer.exe` at second at notification time - hwnd already not useful and `idEventThread` thread can already exit - so unclear what you want get by this way

Comment: WMI can give you events when processes are created and terminated: [Receiving a WMI Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013.aspx)

Comment: This reads like you don't know, what problem you are trying to solve. You are talking about callbacks for processes that are terminating. Yet, when explaining your attempts to solve this, you keep referring to windows. Windows are owned by processes, but there is no relationship between a window being destroyed, and a process that's terminating. You need to provide a succinct problem statement first.